# Android Studio - package java.awt.image does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem running my project on Android Studio. I am working on an Android project that has a native Java library inside it. It was running fine all the time. But suddenly when I open Android Studio, I find this error:

[image]

There is also an error in the .gradle of the project:

[image]

It says that URI is not registered.

When Android Studio is started, I find this message:

[image]

It seems that there is something wrong in Java configuration, but I can't find out what is the problem?

Comment: Try invalidate cache and restart.

Comment: @Ibrahim I have tried this but not working

Answer (score 0):

> It was running fine all the time

Not on Android, it wasn't.

> It seems that there is something wrong in Java configuration

No. You are using classes that are not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: It was running and we uploaded many builds of it. The native Java classes are compiled using NDK and it is integrated fine.

Comment: @AmaniElsaed: Regardless, those Java classes have never existed in the Android SDK. You cannot refer to them at compile time, as they will not resolve. You cannot refer to them at runtime, as you will get a `VerifyError` or `ClassNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

The java Swing and AWT API are not part of the Android SDK and thus aren't including with it. You must find an Android equivalent image library to use in your app. There are few good ones around just depends on what functionality you need to have available to you in you app. Try searching [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and or [Volley](https://github.com/google/volley). Picasso is very popular and well known. it has a lot of feature including networking functionality for loading images from the web. The Volley library isn't an image library but an networking library that contains some predefined classes for loading images over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

So this just happened to me.  I'm not 100% on the details of how I got it working again, but its roughly this (on my Mac):

1. Quit Android Studio
2. I went to ~/Library/Application%20Support/ and deleted the AndroidStudio3.2 directory
3. I relaunched Android Studio and I got some warning dialog about plugins not existing.
4. Chose the button that is something about reinstalling or fixing (or whatever isn't deleting or ignoring)
5. Another dialog comes up.  There are a bunch of plugins that are in red.  Deselect all the red ones.  Then reselect all those ones that were previously red.
6. Android Studio asks you something and if you want to restart Android Studio.  Pick the thing that includes restarting.

And once Android Studio restarts, chose to rebuild your project, and then it worked.

Good Luck and I hope this works for you too.